# Python "ModuleNotFoundError: no module named 'numbers'"

Tags: python, numpy

I was trying to install and use numpy for a project that I am working on and got the error

```
module 'numbers' has no attribute Integral
```

and then found this solution:

https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/9872#issuecomment-337098073

which basically said that I might have other files named "numbers.py" that would conflict with the numbers module. So, sort of stupidly, I deleted all of the "numbers.py" files except for the ones that were installed with numpy, and now I am getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

 File "/var/folders/hw/cyqjhjm96tg8954yh9lrq9380000gn/T/tmpvuuam3s5pycharm-management/setuptools-40.8.0/setup.py", line 11, in <module>
    import setuptools
  File "/private/var/folders/hw/cyqjhjm96tg8954yh9lrq9380000gn/T/tmpvuuam3s5pycharm-management/setuptools-40.8.0/setuptools/__init__.py", line 20, in <module>
    from setuptools.dist import Distribution, Feature
  File "/private/var/folders/hw/cyqjhjm96tg8954yh9lrq9380000gn/T/tmpvuuam3s5pycharm-management/setuptools-40.8.0/setuptools/dist.py", line 9, in <module>
    import numbers
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numbers'
```

whenever I try to run my program with PyCharm (which "cannot create an interpreter"), and when I try to run it in IDLE instead, I get

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/caleb/Documents/neuroanatomy comp lab py3 version.py", line 2, in <module>
    import numpy
  File "/Users/caleb/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages/numpy/__init__.py", line 140, in <module>
    from . import core
  File "/Users/caleb/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages/numpy/core/__init__.py", line 70, in <module>
    from . import numerictypes as nt
  File "/Users/caleb/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages/numpy/core/numerictypes.py", line 566, in <module>
    _register_types()
  File "/Users/caleb/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages/numpy/core/numerictypes.py", line 561, in _register_types
    numbers.Integral.register(integer)
AttributeError: module 'numbers' has no attribute 'Integral'
```

I am not really sure what to do at this point. For reference, I am running MacOS Catalina.
Please help, computer gods!

Comment: Which way did you install numpy? pip? Do you use a distribution like Anaconda?

Comment: @BrianMcCutchon - How in the world is OP going to do that?

Comment: As for tracking down a `numbers.py` without `Integral`, `import numbers;print(numbers.__file__)`. Is the file in one of python's standard install directories?

Comment: @BrianMcCutchon - The failing imports are shown in the tracebacks.

Comment: How many numbers.py were there? if you deleted the one in the base of the standard python libs, its just a case of hunting down another copy of that file and moving it back into place. How that's done depends on operating system and how you installed.

Comment: @Samufi A long time ago I downloaded Anaconda for a school assignment, but I have since deleted it. This time I downloaded it with pip.

Comment: @tdelaney There were several numbers.py files, I would guess that there were around twenty. I put them all back from the trash can, but I still get the same error. I just checked where the original files went, and it looks like most of them went back to their original place but were renamed numbers + *insert time* .py

Comment: Which "it"? numpy? `numbers.py` is in the base python distribution. You may be able to delete and reinstall the entire python distribution - IF its not integral to your operating system. If its anaconda for instance - and you haven't been editing your own modules in the anaconda directory itself  - you could uninstall anaconda (I think just deleting the directory does it - but don't quote me) and reinstall.

Comment: That's odd about the numbers.py files. I'n not sure why you'd have a bunch of timestamped versions of the file. Is this anaconda on windows? I don't have that setup so can't really say why.

Comment: Maybe you could post what's in `sys.path` so we see what your package tree looks like.

Comment: uninstall numpy, restart comp and reinstall numpy, I am 100% this will solve ur issue.

Comment: @tdelaney I just uninstalled and reinstalled anaconda and everything works again (I don't know why it wasn't entirely deleted--I probably just tried deleting the app or something). Thank you!

Comment: @CYREX - How would reinstalling numpy fix a problem with one of the standard python modules?